# Cannot debug projects in Visual Studio 2010 or 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I own two versions of Visual Studio Ultimate 2010 and 2012, and I am having problems with both!

In Visual Studio 2010, once I create a new C++ project (Windows application) and press "Start Debugging", I receive an error message:

> Unable to start program c:\...
>
> The System can't find the specific file.

However, with Ultimate 2012, once I create a new C# project (Windows application) and run it disappears in a second!

Note: I haven't added that much code yet!

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace projecttotest
    {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void closeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void aboutToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("This Application is ..");
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: For the c# : I've added a simple code "Messagebox" but nothing changed at all.  For the c++: the path was :  C:\Users\Sarah\Dropbox\MyNewWork\projecttotest\Debug\ projecttotest.exe, but there is no projecttotest.exe in the same path!

Comment: New Project> Visual C# > Windows Forms Application , & name it as projecttotest. Oh, yeah, I have chosen .Net Framework 4. I added MenuStrip, & add New, Tools, Help as a menu value. Under name, I added Close(); & under help, there is About which have massagebox. All these started after I add close & massageBox, everything was perfect before. I recreate anew one & I haven't added anything the same thing.